# IIS7 ASP-Classic Parameters Lost

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7

I have an ASP-Classic website, which uses a VBScript called ASPXTOASP.ASP to convert .Net request parameters into Classic request parameters after authentication. Authentication takes place using login.aspx, which uses Active Directory to check that the user logged into Windows has permission to view the website. Login.aspx finishes, dumping the user onto ASPXTOASP.ASP, which immediately crashes because the parameters it needs to iterate through have disappeared. When I write the query string at the top of the page it is blank. The login.aspx would redirect me to a different page if it failed. This leads me to believe that somehow, between those two programs, IIS/ASP is dumping my parameters. What's weird is that production works. This problem has only cropped up on the dev box and only for this particular application which works over HTTPS. We have an application that uses the same authentication method on HTTP and it still works.

Things I have checked:

1. Application pool is the same on prod and dev
2. Browser dev console shows the request submitting the proper parameters
3. Certificate appears correct. Browser gives no certificate error

This is the contents of the ASPXTOASP.ASP program which is crashing:

```
<%
'Response.Write "Query String: " & Request.QueryString
'Response.End
for i=1 to Request.Form.Count  

Session(Request.Form.Key(i))=Request.Form(i)
'Response.write( i & ": " & Request.Form.Key(i) & ": " & Request.Form(i) & "<BR>")
next

'Response.End

Server.Transfer(Session("DestPage"))


%>
```

Comment: How you are saving parameters? Please show some code. Are you using Cookies or Session state for passing data?

Comment: I post the variables to login.aspx, which reads them as Request object properties. It writes them into a self-submitting form as form values and that form's action is ASPXTOASP.ASP. Examining the request body in IE shows that the data is submitted. ASPXTOASP.ASP has been added to the main post.